# Can you write the correlation matrix of AR-2 (or AR-p)?

Tags: autoregressive, generalized-estimating-equations

It is easy to write the autoregressive of order 1 (AR-1) correlation matrix:

$$R_{k-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 &\rho &\rho^2 &\cdots &\rho^{k-2} \\
        \rho &1 &\rho &\cdots  &\rho^{k-3} \\
        \rho^2 &\rho &1 & &\rho^{k-4} \\
        \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\ 
        \rho^{k-2} &\rho^{k-3} &\cdots &   &1\\
        \
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Can this be done for other orders, e.g. AR-2, or AR-M?

The reason I'm asking is that doing a likelihood analysis in GEE we can specify a correlation matrix. So I was wondering how it looks like there.

Comment: It will be a Toeplitz matrix of the same diagonal form you have shown for ar1

Comment: Why is this community so bad. I just don't get it. I rarely get a decent answer on a question. More like a "go fetch". I quit. Enough is enough.

Comment: @Kjetil That's only a partial answer -- and not terribly useful at that.  Exactly what values would be on the diagonal, as a function of the model parameters?